# What music theory helps me to understand an Em - Cm progression?

Tags: chord-progressions

I find this progression quite beautiful to improvise with. I would really love to know if there is a theoretical way to understand it. It is outside of any tonality that I know about.

What is the relation between these chords? What other chords would help me to build something after it? Should I mix the Em and Cm tonalities and get some hybrid there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The relationship is known as a “chromatic mediant”, and it’s quite significant in a number of musical styles. There are four possible chromatic mediant related chords from any starting chord, and each has their own flavor.

The definition of a chromatic mediant relationship is that the two triads are 1) the same quality, and 2) have roots a third apart. In your example, 1) both triads are minor, and 2) the root of the second chord is a major third below that of the first. Other chords with the same kind of relationship to Em are C#m, Gm and G#m. Any two chords that are chromatic mediant a of each other will have the same kinds of connections with each other:

1) There will be one common tone. In your example this is the G.

2) There will be one stepwise movement. In your example, that’s the C moving to B.

3) There will be one chromatic shift. In your example that’s the E becoming Eb.

If you check, you’ll see that these same relationships always apply so long as the qualities of the two triads stay the same, and the roots are a third apart.

Comment: A good example of chromatic mediant motion, the same type as Em to Cm but Bm to Gm, is in Schubert's _Der Wegweiser_ from his songcycle _Winterreise._  In this clip, it happens at 1:32.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXYk6D4gM6w

Comment: The 'chromatic (sub)mediant' idea is attractive, but Em - Dm also sounds good.    And a non-chromatic mediant (Cmajor - Emajor) is LOVELY.  You can hang a label on anything, but it doesn't necessarily explain anything.   Play around with Cmajor - F#major.  That's nice too.

Comment: @LaurencePayne Cmajor - Emajor *is* a chromatic mediant. Two triads of the same quality with roots a third apart: E is the common tone, C–B the stepwise motion, G–G# the chromatic shift. Anyway, I’m at a loss as to why you read my answer about the mechanics of a specific chord connection as somehow being a rejection of other chord connections.

Comment: Just that 'Chromatic mediant' seems to be a 'thing' while other shifts, with just as much validity, aren't :-)

Answer (score 3):

Pat's answer is the proper technical one (+1), but it could also be regarded as chords from a parallel key. If the key was C major, the Em would be diatonic. Parallel key to C is C minor, so it's a chord that could well feature in the same piece.

Comment: Just curious : if you mix concepts of diatonic chords and parallel key, cannot you build every chord?

Comment: Not exactly. Take C. Diatonics are C,  Dm, Em, F, G, Am, Bo. Parallel Cm. Diatonics now are Cm, Do, Eb, Fm, Gm, Ab, Bb. That's not 'every chord' by a long chalk. I'm keeping to basic triads for simplicity.

Comment: @Tim But the question was about two chords (The relationship between chords X and Y is that chord X is in Z major and chord Y is in Z minor). The chord C occurs also for example in G major, so all chords in G major and G minor are also related to C in that way. And also in A minor, so you should include all chords in A major. That's a lot more than in your list.

Comment: @JiK - true, I was trying to keep it simplish, but it still remains true that it's not *every* chord.